# Error 83118834 when trying to open session in Xbox Live

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

I switched on my Xbox 360 after several weeks without using it and I'm receiving the error 83118834 when trying to open session in Xbox Live. I tried it several times and after confirming the password of my Live account it seems to connect but after a few seconds the error appears again. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm asking the question although I figured the answer myself because I couldn't find the right answer anywhere (there are several questions about the same topic without answer in the forsaken waste that is answers.microsoft.com).

Comment: Also I can't understand why MS ever bothers to give a specific error code if they aren't posting what the error means in any of their web sites, even a generic "Problem with your account information".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the answer myself, I remembered that several days ago I received an email from Microsoft asking to update the information of my account (in my case my birth date), which I had ignored, so I did the following:

- Went to https://www.xbox.com/
- Pressed "Sign in" to open session.
- Entered account ID/email & password using the same account that I use for the Xbox.
- After doing that, I was asked for the missing information (my birth date), I entered it and continued.

After finishing this, I switched on the console again and it connected to Xbox Live at the first try.

Hope that this help other people.